# Overwrite value in the difference instance variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Why am I getting the previous value into the different instance variables?

For example:

```py
d1 = myDict()
d2 = myDict()
d1.assign(2,3)
d2.assign(2,2)
print(d1.getval(2))
print(d2.getval(2))
```

```py
class myDict(object):
    """ Implements a dictionary without using a dictionary """
    aDict = {}
    def __init__(self):
        """ initialization of your representation """
        #FILL THIS IN

    def assign(self, k, v):
        """ k (the key) and v (the value), immutable objects  """
        #FILL THIS IN
        self.k = k
        self.v = v
        if self.k not in myDict.aDict:
            self.aDict[self.k] = self.v
        else:
            self.aDict[self.k] = self.v

    def getval(self, k):
        """ k, immutable object  """
        #FILL THIS IN

        if k in myDict.aDict:
            return myDict.aDict[k]
        else:
            KeyError ('KeyError successfully raised')

        # return myDict.aDict[k]

    def delete(self, k):
        """ k, immutable object """   
        #FILL THIS IN
        if k in myDict.aDict.keys():

            del myDict.aDict[k]
        else:
            raise KeyError('KeyError successfully raised')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(myDict.aDict)



d1 = myDict()
d2 = myDict()
d1.assign(2,3)
d2.assign(2,2)
print(d1.getval(2))
print(d2.getval(2))
```

My output:

```
2
2
4
1
```

Correct output:

```
3
2
4
1
```

Comment: I am getting previous instance variable value even though I declared two different instance variable

Comment: If your task is to implement dictionary without using a dictionary, you shouldn't be using ``aDict = {}`` - a dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`aDict` has been defined as a class level attribute, this means that all instances of `myDict` will share the same `aDict`.

To assign a separate `aDict` for each instance you should do this in the `__init__` method

```
def __init__(self):
    self.aDict = {}
```

Comment: You are awesome bro. I finally made the full grade in the course. because of this small problem, I was losing 6 points. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `aDict` is not an instance variable, but a static variable. This means there exists only one `aDict` instance on a class-level which is shared by all instances of your `myDict` class. As a result, any changes you make to `aDict` in any given `myDict` instance will be reflected in all `myDict` instances.

In addition, I'd like to point out that you're not following the instructions of the assignment. The docstring of your class says you must implement this class without using a dictionary.